# how to add a new record to postgresql database using sails v.1?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, orm, controller, sails.js

I'm trying to add a new user to the users' table that I have in PostgreSQL database. there is no problem when I use findOne() method but when I use create() nothing happens. here is some of my configuration:

**model(users.js)**

```
    var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
module.exports = {

  tableName: "users",
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'number',
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    first_name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    last_name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      isEmail: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
  },
}
```

**usersController.js**

```
registerUser: function (req, res) {
bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) return res.send('An error occured', 500);

    console.log(hash);
    // Save user to the database
    Users.create({
       first_name: req.body.first_name,
       last_name: req.body.last_name,
       email: req.body.email,
       password: hash
    }).exec(function(err, user){
        if (err) return res.send('An error occured', 500);
        console.log(user)
    })

});
}
```

and i set my **datastore.js** file to:

```
    default: {
    adapter: require('sails-postgresql'),
    url: 'postgresql://username:password@host:5432/db-name', 
  },
```

and finally, in my models.js in config folder, i set `migrate:'safe'` and i commented the schema and attributes.

````
    module.exports.models = {

  // schema: false,

  migrate: 'safe',
  attributes: {
    // createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
    // updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },
    // id: { type: 'number', autoIncrement: true, },
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  /\   Using MongoDB?
    //  ||   Replace `id` above with this instead:
    //
    // ```
    // id: { type: 'string', columnName: '_id' },
    // ```
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  },
  dataEncryptionKeys: {
    default: '/ZBj9EC29Xb+mNULkmFn3NuYUK9wDLJdWQ4U2lNR7+w='
  },

  cascadeOnDestroy: true
};
````

every thing seems to be ok but i don't know what the problem is?